# NDK is not installed, Android artifact creation fails in Azure Pipeline

Tags: android-ndk

Ive used the following YAML config:

Gradle
Build your Java project and run tests with Gradle using a Gradle wrapper script.
Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/java

trigger:

- develop

pool:
vmImage: 'macOS-10.14'

steps:

- task: Gradle@2
  inputs:
  workingDirectory: ''
  gradleWrapperFile: 'gradlew'
  gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
  javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
  jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
  jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
  publishJUnitResults: false
  testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
  tasks: 'build'

---

I see the issue mentioned below:

Task :app:compileLiasDevReleaseSources
Task :app:lintVitalLiasDevRelease SKIPPED

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Task :app:extractLiasDevReleaseNativeSymbolTables FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:extractLiasDevReleaseNativeSymbolTables'.

NDK is not installed

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

```
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
213 actionable tasks: 213 executed
in 7m 37s
Error: The process '/Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew' failed with exit code 1
at ExecState._setResult (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.191.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:944:25)
at ExecState.CheckComplete (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.191.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:927:18)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/runner/work/_tasks/Gradle_8d8eebd8-2b94-4c97-85af-839254cc6da4/2.191.0/node_modules/azure-pipelines-task-lib/toolrunner.js:840:19)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:389:11)
at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
at Pipe._handle.close (net.js:607:12)
```

[error]Error: The process '/Users/runner/work/1/s/gradlew' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Gradle